# custom View or ScrollView component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to create custom template like below code and export it and reuse ?

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

const CustomView = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Test 1 </Text>
            *** custom code ***
        </View>
    )
}

export default CustomView
```

now how do I use the CustomView above and add my own tag for example

```
import CustomView from "../CustomView";
 return (
            <CustomView>
                <Text>Test 2 </Text>
            </CustomView>
        )
```

so when I run my output will be

```
Test 1
Test 2
```

Can we do something like this ? So I can organise my code better by reusing templates.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible and would be good practice doing so. If you want to put other components inside your custom component the custom component would be the parent component and the parts inside would be the children.

CustomView.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

const CustomView = ({ children }) => {
  return (
      <View>
          <Text>Test 1</Text>
          {children}
      </View>
  )
}

export default CustomView;
```

App.js (or another file)

```
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";


const App = () => {
  return (
    <CustomView>
      <Text>Test 2</Text>
    </CustomView>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You would of course need to style your custom component. Don't forget, the best practice is to always create as many reusable components as you can. More code doesn't mean better code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another example of custom or reusable Components.

MyTextInput.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Dimensions,
    TextInput
} from 'react-native';
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

export default MyTextInput = ({placeholder, onChangeText, value, secureTextEntry, keyboardType}) => {

    return (
        <View style={inputContainerStyle}>
          <TextInput
            secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
            style={inputStyle}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            onChangeText={onChangeText}
            value={value}
            placeholderTextColor="#9B9A9B"
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            keyboardType={keyboardType}
          />
        </View>
    )
}

const inputContainerStyle = {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: width * 0.90,
    height: height * 0.06,
    borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
    borderBottomColor: "#9B9A9B",
    marginTop: height * 0.02,
    paddingBottom: height * 0.02,
  };
  
  const inputStyle = {
    flex: 1, 
    fontSize: 15,
    color: "#9B9A9B",
  };
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import MyTextInput from './MyTextInput';

export default function App() {

  return (
    <View style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
      <MyTextInput
        placeholder="Password"
        onChangeText={onPasswordChange}
        value={password}
        secureTextEntry={this.state.showPassword}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```